# fork() 4 children in a loop

Tags: c, linux, fork

The goal is to try and fork 4 children in a loop, but I'm not sure how to properly do that. This is what I have so far. I tried to draw it out and I think I'm not waiting to reap the child properly. And I create like 2 children every iteration. So, 8 children in total.

```
void main() {
  int i = 0;
  pid_t pid;
  int status;

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) {
      /* Child Process */
      fork();
      exit(0); 
    } else {
      /* Parent Process */
      wait(&status);
      printf("At i = %d, process %d is terminated.\n", i, pid);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are the processes related? Like is it a chain `P0 -> P1 -> P2 -> P3` or a single parent `P0 -> P1, P2, P3` or something else?

Comment: your second `fork` (in child process) will create a mess and it will probably cause an unlimited number of processes, killing your operating system. get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating four children processes from the same parent process can be achieved by *forking* once on each iteration of the `for` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pid_t pid = fork();

      if (pid == 0)
         exit(0); // child process

      // parent process
      wait(NULL);
      printf("At i = %d, process %d is terminated.\n", i, pid);
   }
}
```

However, you probably want the parent process to wait for the children **after** it has created all of the four children, because you usually want the children to do something before exiting and concurrently with the other children:

```
int main() {
   // create the four children processes
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pid_t pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0) {
         // child process
         // ... do some stuff ...
         exit(0);
      }
   }

   // wait for the four children processes to finish
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      pid_t pid = wait(NULL);
      printf("Process %d is terminated.\n", pid);
   }
}
```

Comment: For the second version, how is it gonna know which child is which because it's created and exited immediately 4 times before it's able to get out of the loop.

Comment: @Siv You can call [`wait(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) in order to wait for any child process or [`waitpid(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for waiting for a child process with a particular *PID*. Note that `wait(2)` returns the *PID* of the child the parent process waited for.

Comment: I think I'm getting it now. After the child exiting, it's still technically there, right? I think it's called Zombie Process? That's how the wait() knows what to do cuz of the existence of the Zombie Process.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot.

Comment: @Siv Yes, the child process stays as a zombie process after finishing so that the parent process can retrieve its status.